# Content-based routing in MassTransit

Tags: .net, esb, masstransit

Is it possible to do content-based routing in MassTransit? Is it generally a good practice to use Enterprise Service Bus for content-based routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally content-based routing is frowned upon (e.g. http://www.udidahan.com/2011/03/20/careful-with-content-based-routing/) and not considered a good practice. MassTransit does not support content based routing. Routing is normally done on types.

Given that, I have done an implementation for a specific product that had content based routing done as a custom distributor implementation on MSMQ. This was the take some content to a "slow lane" during the load balancing process. This was narrow and scope and deems okay for the specific needs. That is the only time I've used it though - proper use of message types for routing is easier to maintain and manage.

Comment: Thanks. I might not be understanding the definitions well but doesn't Consumes<T>.Selected provide sort of content-based routing?

Comment: Nope. It just rejects messages going into the consumer. The message has already been routed by that point.

Comment: And use of .Selected is highly discouraged - in fact, so much so it's deprecated in MT3.